# Volume of a given solid?

Tags: volume

Passed by a question now, need a volume of a given solid but I can't understand how to draw such a solid.

The region is given by : 
$S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x| + 2|y| \le 1-z^2\}.$

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute the volumes as integrals of cross-sections.

Consider the sections given by the intersection of our solid $S$ and the plane $z=t$ with $t\in [-1,1]$ (because $|x| + 2|y|\geq 0$ implies $1-t^2\geq 0$).

Note that $|x| + 2|y|\leq 1-t^2$ is a rhombus in the plane $z=t$ with diagonals along the $x$-axis and $y$-axis. It is easy to see that the lengths of those diagonals are $2(1-t^2)$ and $(1-t^2)$. Therefore its area is $\frac{1}{2}[2(1-t^2)\cdot(1-t^2)]=(1-t^2)^2$.
Therefore 
$$\mbox{volume}(S)=\int_{t=-1}^1\left(\iint_{|x| + 2|y|\leq 1-t^2}1 dx dy\right) dt\\=\int_{-1}^1\mbox{area}\left(\{|x| + 2|y|\leq 1-t^2\}\right) dt\\
=\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^2 dt=\frac{16}{15}.$$

Comment: is there then a common area formula of quadrilateral to be used, cant figure out an integral formula to get them, and may i ask why limit $z$ in the domain of [0,1] only?

Comment: @Mohamad Misto Sorry the range for $t$ is $[-1,1]$ because the left hand side is non negative and $1-t^2\geq 0$

Comment: @Mohamad Misto Is everything clear now?

Comment: Yep now i understood really good, ty for the help